# Meteor With windows Not working

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor .I am using windows platform to build application for mobile but i am unable to make it run on android as it says unsupported not working.
please guide me step wise to deploy my app onto my android smartphone with windows

Comment: add platform command doesnt work too

Answer (score 3):

Mobile builds for Android and iOS are currently not supported on Windows ([support for Android seems to be planned](https://forums.meteor.com/t/improvements-to-mobile-support/6817) (see point no. 5), but iOS will still requires Xcode to run).
So, while you can develop and test in your browser on Windows, you will need at least a Linux install to run/build your app for Android devices, and/or a mac (or an OS X VM) to run/build for iOS devices.